# How do I presist data from the view during EDIT GET to EDIT POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a dilemma that I hope someone can help me with.  During the Edit Get stage of loading and updating a page before it is loaded, I store the checkboxes that are checked like this:

```
foreach (var course in courses.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
{
    @:  <td>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="selectedCourses" value="@course.Data.CourseID"
            @(Html.Raw(course.Data.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
        </td>
    bool theNewString = course.Data.Assigned;
    String a = theNewString.ToString();
    assignedCourses.Add(a);
}
```

At the top of the view I defined the list to store the data like this so that I can be sent in the BeginForm:

```
@{ List<String> assignedCourses = new List<String>(); }
```

Then I try to send the list to the Edit POST like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { assigned = assignedCourses }))
```

In my controller signature looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, List<String> assigned)
```

The list is loaded at the end of the get stage but the data in the list does not go through to Edit POST. My question is how do I get the list that I created at the end of the edit get stage to persist so that I can use it in my post?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try make this as simple as possible. So your `Course` model is something like this...

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

...and you want to display some saved values on screen to edit. So starting at the controller, I've dummied some data and set one of the `Assigned` booleans to `true` so it is checked when the page loads.

```
public Controller Courses
{
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var courses = new Course[] {
            new Course() { Id = 1, Name = "maths", Assigned = true },
            new Course() { Id = 2, Name = "english", Assigned = false },
            new Course() { Id = 3, Name = "science", Assigned = false }
        };

        return View(courses);
    }
```

Now, your page should expect a collection of these courses, so at the top of your page define the type that the `View` is expecting...

**cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<ExampleProject.Domain.Course>
```

...which you can then enumerate through in your `View` and create your checkboxes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Courses", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <label for="@item.Id">@item.Name</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="courses" id="@item.Id" value="@item.Id" checked="@item.Assigned" />
    }

    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
}
```

This will render the following html:

```
<label for="1">maths</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="courses" id="1" value="1" checked="checked">

<label for="2">english</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="courses" id="2" value="2">

<label for="3">science</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="courses" id="3" value="3">
```

Now you can check what you like and submit your form. In true http fashion your controller action will receive the values were checked on the `View`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Courses(int id, int[] courses)
{
    // courses will contain the values of the checkboxes that were checked
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); // etc
}
```

Hopefully this helps. You can be a bit smarter and use the Html helpers for some more complicated binding (eg. `Html.CheckBox`, `Html.CheckBoxFor`) but this should get you going and it's clear to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks this does work.  It does give me the checked courses.  I was hoping to get the checked and unchecked data in a list so that I can use that data in the controller.  However this does answer my question.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Darin's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557952/609176) might help you if you're looking to use the `CheckBoxFor` helper and you require a `true` or `false` for all items in your collection.